# Load an Image from QUrl to QImage (Qt Framework)

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qimage, qurl

I am trying to load an image from QML using its source. In main.qml I have:

```
Image {
    id: photoFiltering
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height/2
    anchors.leftMargin: 20
    anchors.rightMargin: 20
    anchors.bottomMargin: 20
}
```

and

```
Button{
            id: filtersButtons
            text: "Filter"
            anchors.top: photoFiltering.bottom
            anchors.horizontalCenter: photoFiltering.horizontalCenter
            onClicked: ()=>{
                filterController.setFilterType(filterController.Original);
                var filteredImage = filterController.filterImage(photoFiltering.source);
            }
        }
```

Thus in my C++ code I ma trying to do the following:

```
QImage FilterController::filterImage(QString imageSource)
{
    QImage image;
    bool loaded = image.load(imageSource);
    cout << "image laoded " << loaded << endl;
     ...
    return image;
}
```

The problem is I can't simply load the image like that to get the Object QImage. What Should I do to get that image?

Comment: Have you looked at [QQuickImageProvider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qquickimageprovider.html)?

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to retrieve a QImage from a QUrl:

- Instantiates a QNetworkAccessManager
- Turns your QUrl into a QNetworkRequest
- Invokes QNetworkAccessManager::get()
- Asynchronously wait for the QNetworkAccessManager::finished() signal
- Use QNetworkReply::readAll() to get the QByteArray
- Use QImage::loadFromData to populate a QImage

Below is an ImageUtil helper class for doing the above:

```cpp
//ImageUtil.h
#ifndef __ImageUtil__
#define __ImageUtil__

#include <QObject>
#include <QImage>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>

class ImageUtil : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ImageUtil(QObject* parent = nullptr) :
        QObject(parent),
        m_Manager(new QNetworkAccessManager(this))
    {
        connect(m_Manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &ImageUtil::onFinished);
    }

    const QImage& image() const { return m_Image; }
    Q_INVOKABLE void loadFromUrl(const QUrl& url)
    {
        QNetworkRequest request(url);
        m_Manager->get(request);
    }

signals:
    void loaded();

protected slots:
    void onFinished(QNetworkReply* reply)
    {
        QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
        m_Image.loadFromData(data);
        emit loaded();
    }

protected:
    QImage m_Image;
    QNetworkAccessManager* m_Manager;

};

#endif
```

This is a test of the class:

```cpp
void test()
{
    ImageUtil* imageUtil = new ImageUtil();
    imageUtil->loadFromUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"));
    imageUtil->connect(imageUtil, &ImageUtil::loaded,
                       [=]() {
        QImage image = imageUtil->image();
        qDebug() << image.width() << image.height(); // 272 92
    });
}
```

Please treat the above code as a guide only and do not expect it to stand up in a production environment. For you to do a proper job, you really need to understand:

- Qt signal/slot mechanism
- asynchronous programming
- proper patterns for instantiating and cleaning classes (the test code, in particular, is leaky, so some effort is required to make a proper test)
- there is no HTTP error handling (invalid HTTP/HTTPS request, poor or no internet connectivity, 404 errors (i.e. no image), HTTPS/SSL certificate errors, other HTTP status errors
- there is no image handling (the downloaded content may not be a valid image)

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP wants to load a QImage from a URL.

Comment: @relent95 thanks. I rewrote the answer accordingly.

Comment: @StephenQuan But does this work if URL is local path of an image?

Comment: @AhmadWehbe the above example will work for both http and file uri. However, if we know we want to load from a local file, then the above implementation would be over-engineering, since, we would simply use QImage's load().